# Testing @ModelAttribute method on a controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, spring-test

This are the annotated methods in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getClient(@PathVariable("contractUuid") UUID contractUuid, Model model) {
    ClientDto clientDto = new ClientDto();
    clientDto.setContractUuid(contractUuid);
    model.addAttribute("client", clientDto);
    return "addClient";
}

@ModelAttribute("contract")
public ContractDto getContract(@PathVariable("contractUuid") UUID contractUuid) throws ContractNotFoundException {
    return contractService.fromEntity(contractService.findByUuid(contractUuid));
}
```

The test method that I am trying is shown below, but it fails for attribute **contract**. The attribute **client** is added to the **Model** in a **@RequestMapping** method.

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Autowired
private ContractService contractServiceMock;
@Autowired
private ClientService clientServiceMock;
@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void setup() {
    Mockito.reset(contractServiceMock);
    Mockito.reset(clientServiceMock);
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    Contract contract = new Contract(uuid);

    when(contractServiceMock.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(contract);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/addClient/{contractUuid}", uuid))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("addClient"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/pages/addClient.jsp"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("client"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("contract"));
}
```

The **contract** attribute shows in the jsp page when I run the application, since I use some of its attributes, but since it fails in the test method is there another way to test it ?
It fails with the message:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'contract' does not exist

Spring is 4.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: can you post too the @RequestMapping method?

Comment: You are testing addClient, show that

Comment: @NimChimpsky you want me to show the test class for addCLient ?

Comment: The URL you are testing is addClient...

Comment: yes, but the Model for that URL must also have a contract attribute retrieved from the @ModeAttribute method.

Comment: What Spring version are you on? Also, please explain what you mean by _it fails_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added further information to the question

Comment: And, finally, let's see your MVC configuration.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I found the culprit. It was my mistake in not mocking the contractServiceMock.fromEntity method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was my fault.
Even though the **@ModelAttribute** method returns an instance of **ContractDto** I only mocked one method used from the service:

```
when(contractServiceMock.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(contract);
```

and so **findByUuid** returned something, but **contractService.fromEntity** was left untouched so I had to also mock it:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    Contract contract = new Contract(uuid);
    ContractDto contractDto = new ContractDto(uuid);

    when(contractServiceMock.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(contract);
    when(contractServiceMock.fromEntity(contract)).thenReturn(contractDto);
```